# Python OpenAI's gym Error (AttributeError: 'Timer' object has no attribute '_seed')

Tags: python, openai-gym

I'm using Python 3.5.3 and Debian 9

I tried to run this example code from Universe's blog:

```py
import gym
import universe

env = gym.make('flashgames.DuskDrive-v0') #problem here
env.configure(remotes=1)
observation_n = env.reset()

while True:
  action_n = [[('KeyEvent', 'ArrowUp', True)] for ob in observation_n]
  observation_n, reward_n, done_n, info = env.step(action_n)
  env.render()
```

And I got this error:

```
WARN: Environment '<class 'universe.wrappers.timer.Timer'>' has deprecated methods '_step' and '_reset' rather than 'step' and 'reset'. Compatibility code invoked. Set _gym_disable_underscore_compat = True to disable this behavior.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "universe_test.py", line 4, in <module>
    env = gym.make('flashgames.DuskDrive-v0')
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gym/envs/registration.py", line 167, in make
    return registry.make(id)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gym/envs/registration.py", line 125, in make
    patch_deprecated_methods(env)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gym/envs/registration.py", line 185, in patch_deprecated_methods
    env.seed  = env._seed
AttributeError: 'Timer' object has no attribute '_seed'
```

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51760218/attributeerror-timer-object-has-no-attribute-seed) question which asks the same thing but isn't answered.

Can you guys help me solve this problem and run the program?